# Can users see all of the same cases when assigned to the same location in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Suppose I have a location (called "parent") at a location level that has "View Child Data" turned on. I have two users assigned to that location ("user1" and "user2"). The location has a child location called "child".

Is it true that "user1" and "user2" will both sync the cases owned by the users at the "child" location, but that "user1" will not sync cases assigned to "user2" (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive that's correct.  You could run a quick test and use the Reassign Cases feature to assign a case from the location to user1 then see if user2 gets it when you sync.